# How to manage opennebula sandbox on VirtualBox using opennebula API

Tags: java, eclipse, sandbox, ide, api

I want to manage different cloud resources using opennebula API.
For that I installed opennebula sandbox based CentOS 7 on a VirtualBox VM. 
When I tried to execute my class in the eclipse IDE that allocate a simple virtual machine, I failed: 
This is the code:

```
package org.opennebula;

import org.opennebula.client.Client;
import org.opennebula.client.OneResponse;
import org.opennebula.client.vm.VirtualMachine;

public class Alloue {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Client oneClient;

   try {

       String one_auth="oneadmin:opennebula";
       String one_xmlrpc="http://localhost:2633/RPC2";

       oneClient=new Client(one_auth,one_xmlrpc);

       String vmTemplate =
               "NAME     = vm_from_java    CPU = 0.1    MEMORY = 64\n";


            System.out.println("Virtual Machine Template:\n" + vmTemplate);
            System.out.println();

            System.out.print("Trying to allocate the virtual machine... ");
            OneResponse rc = VirtualMachine.allocate(oneClient, vmTemplate);

            if( rc.isError() )
            {
                System.out.println( "failed!");
                throw new Exception( rc.getErrorMessage() );
            }

       else
           System.out.println("ok");
    }

    catch(Exception e) {
    }

    }

}
```

How can I resolve this problem ?
How can I manage openenbula-sandbox on VirtualBox with opennebula API?

Output of this code is:

Virtual Machine Template:
NAME = vm_from_java CPU = 0.1 MEMORY = 64

Trying to allocate the virtual machine… failed!

And if i delete one_auth and one_xmlrpc variables from Client variable an error message display:
ONE_AUTH file not present

Comment: And the failure message was...?

Comment: @JeffSchaller   The output of this code is :                                                                             Virtual Machine Template:
NAME     = vm_from_java    CPU = 0.1    MEMORY = 64


Trying to allocate the virtual machine... failed!